# Dynamic service redirections in Docker

Tags: docker, microservices, networking

Imagine you have decided to abstract from exact service location.

Normally, you have a cody world with the service name=DNS.

Say, you have prototyped something with S3 compatible API like exoscale/pithos.

But then you think okay this was actually a mockup and now you go for real S3 in production.

Would you rewrite the stack, trick around with `${ENV_VARIABLES}` or is there some more elegant way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://12factor.net/config, configuration like this should be stored as environment variables.

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

A service that you connect to is suitable to be defined as configuration, so the use of env vars is appropriate here.